# Creating an UDTF using the Snowpark python API

Tags: dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am looking for an example of creating a Vectorized UDTF and registering it all in Snowpark syntax? Can anybody provide a code snippet or links where I can see something like that?

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-tabular-vectorized#getting-started-with-vectorized-python-udtfs) an example on how to create a Vectorized UDFT and [here's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-udtfs#examples) and example of registering a UDF (applies to vectorized as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to create a Vectorized UDFT and here's and example of registering a UDF (applies to vectorized as well).

Something simple like this (make sure you have the latest version of Snowpark) can be tried:

```py
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import pandas_udtf

class multiply_test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.multiplier = 10
    def end_partition(self, df):
        df.columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2']
        df.col1 = df.col1*self.multiplier
        df.col2 = df.col2*self.multiplier
        yield df
multiply_udtf = pandas_udtf(
    multiply_test,
    output_schema=PandasDataFrameType([StringType(), IntegerType(), FloatType()], ["id_", "col1_", "col2_"]),
    input_types=[PandasDataFrameType([StringType(), IntegerType(), FloatType()])],
    session=session
```

Also the links provided by @Sergiu are great:

[Create an UDTF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-tabular-vectorized#getting-started-with-vectorized-python-udtfs)

[Register an UDTF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-udtfs#examples)